# Regular expression, glob, Python

Tags: python, glob

I have a folder, contains many files.
There is a group contains pc_0.txt,pc_1.txt,...,pc_699.txt.
I want to select all files beetween pc_200 - > to pc_699.txt

How?

```
for filename in glob.glob("pc*.txt"):
    global_list.append(filename)
```

Comment: Side-note: If you're just appending each value to the global list, skip the explicit loop and just do: `global_list.extend(glob.glob("pc*.txt"))` (or whatever glob pattern you settle on); letting Python perform the work directly in bulk is faster and cleaner than unnecessary explicit loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this specific case, `glob` already supports what you need (see [`fnmatch` docs for glob wildcards](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch)). You can just do:

```
for filename in glob.glob("pc[23456]??.txt"):
```

If you need to be extra specific that the two trailing characters are numbers (some files might have non-numeric characters there), you can replace the `?`s with `[0123456789]`, but otherwise, I find the `?` a little less distracting.

In a more complicated scenario, you might be forced to resort to regular expressions, and you could do so here with:

```
import re

for filename in filter(re.compile(r'^pc_[2-6]\d\d\.txt$').match, os.listdir('.')):
```

but given that glob-style wildcards work well enough, you don't need to break out the big guns just yet.