# Find pathnames using RegEx patterns instead of globs

Tags: python, regex, glob

Is there a currently available way in Python to search for pathnames using regular expressions when globbing is insufficient? For example,

```py
# Match abc_123/ and abc/ but not abcd_123/ or abcd/
re_glob(r'abc(_123)?')
# Match path/abc_123/to/file.txt but not path/abcd/to/file.txt
re_glob('path/abc(_123)?/to/*.txt')
```

Any example I come up with can be accomplished with globbing followed by regex filtering but I am interested if a simple regex only option is available or straightforward to implement. Looking at similar questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511690/python-get-pathname-of-files-using-regex-pattern-recursively), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031989/regular-expression-usage-in-glob-glob), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052509/regular-expression-glob-python?rq=3)) it seems no such option is proposed or, if it is, it is a naive walk through all subdirectories of the pattern's root folder followed by regex filtering.

If no available solutions exist, any significant downside to extending the [glob.glob() implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/glob.py)? It seems like the only change needed is replacing `fnmatch.filter()` with `re.fullmatch()` and extending `has_magic` to `has_regex`.

Comment: You can loop over the filenames returned by `os.listdir()` and do your own regexp matching.

Comment: Does `\babc(_123)\b?` work for you?

Comment: @Barmar: I agree that works for the simple case of filtering files in a single directory but then it does not generalize if the regular expression applies to directories in the pattern. For example, `re_glob('path/abc(_123)?/to/*.txt')`

Comment: @Bohemian: That also works for my example but I am more interested in whether there exists an implementation of re_glob or what the best way to implement it would be.

Comment: @Barmar. I edited the post to mention that example as I see my example before didn't make clear the kind of cases I was imagining.

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing built-in that does it. You can use `os.walk()` for recursion.